# Nested query to find details in table B for maximum value in table A

Tags: sql, mysql, nested, subquery, max

I've got a huge bunch of `flights` travelling between `airports`.

Each airport has an ID and (x,y) coordinates.

For a given list of flights belonging to a user, I want to find the northernmost (highest y) airport visited.

---

Here's the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT name,iata,icao,apid,x,y 
  FROM airports 
 WHERE y=(SELECT MAX(y) 
            FROM airports AS a
               , flights AS f 
           WHERE (f.src_apid=a.apid OR f.dst_apid=a.apid) AND f.uid=[user_id]
         )
```

This works beautifully and reasonably fast as long as `y` is unique (= there's only one airport at that latitude), but fails once it isn't.  Unfortunately this happens quite often, as eg. military and civilian airports have separate entries even though they occupy the same coordinates.

What I'd really want to do is find the airport with `MAX(y)` in the subquery and return the actual matching airport (`a.apid`), instead of returning the value of `y` and then matching it again.  Any suggestions?

---

Assume the user has only this one flight, from apid '3728':

```
mysql> select * from flights where uid=35 and src_apid=3728 limit 1;
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+-----------+-------+--------+------+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+------+------------+------+
| uid  | src_apid | src_time | dst_apid | distance | code | seat | seat_type | class | reason | plid | alid | trid | fid    | duration | registration | note         | upd_time            | opp  | src_date   | mode |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+-----------+-------+--------+------+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+------+------------+------+
|   35 |     3728 | NULL     |     3992 |     4116 | NW16 | 23C  | A         | Y     | L      |  167 | 3731 | NULL | 107493 | 08:00:00 |              | del. typhoon | 2008-10-04 10:40:58 | Y    | 2001-08-22 | F    | 
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+-----------+-------+--------+------+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+------+------------+------+
```

And there are two airports at the same coordinates:

```
mysql> select * from airports where y=21.318681;
+-----------------------+----------+---------------+------+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+------+----------+------+
| name                  | city     | country       | iata | icao | x           | y         | elevation | apid | uid  | timezone | dst  |
+-----------------------+----------+---------------+------+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+------+----------+------+
| Honolulu Intl         | Honolulu | United States | HNL  | PHNL | -157.922428 | 21.318681 |        13 | 3728 | NULL |      -10 | N    | 
| Hickam Air Force Base | Honolulu | United States |      | PHIK | -157.922428 | 21.318681 |        13 | 7055 |    3 |      -10 | N    | 
+-----------------------+----------+---------------+------+------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------+------+----------+------+
```

If you run the original query, the subquery will return y=21.318681, which in turn will match either apid 3728 (correct) *or* apid 7055 (wrong).

Comment: Can you give a few example rows in airports and flights that shows the problem along with the expected resultset? I'd be happy to help but I don't understand the issue clearly enough.

Comment: The query should be modified to only return airports that the passenger has visited, i.e. in the sample data shown the passenger visited 3728 and 3992, so only one of those airports should be returned, thus eliminated Hickam (apid=7055).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the following query perform?
It works by first finding the northmost Y cordinate in the set of airports visited. Then an identical query is performed which is filtered by the Y coordinate in the previous query. The final step is to find the airport.

```
drop table airports;
drop table flights;

create table airports(
   apid    int         not null
  ,apname  varchar(50) not null
  ,x       int         not null
  ,y       int         not null
  ,primary key(apid)
  ,unique(apname)
);

create table flights(
   flight_id int         not null auto_increment
  ,src_apid  int         not null
  ,dst_apid  int         not null
  ,user_id   varchar(20) not null
  ,foreign key(src_apid) references airports(apid)
  ,foreign key(dst_apid) references airports(apid)
  ,primary key(flight_id)
  ,index(user_id)
);

insert into airports(apid, apname, x, y) values(1, 'Northpole Civilian',     50, 100);
insert into airports(apid, apname, x, y) values(2, 'Northpole Military',     50, 100);
insert into airports(apid, apname, x, y) values(3, 'Transit point',          50, 50);
insert into airports(apid, apname, x, y) values(4, 'Southpole Civilian',     50, 0);
insert into airports(apid, apname, x, y) values(5, 'Southpole Military',     50, 0);

insert into flights(src_apid, dst_apid, user_id) values(4, 3, 'Family guy');
insert into flights(src_apid, dst_apid, user_id) values(3, 1, 'Family guy');

insert into flights(src_apid, dst_apid, user_id) values(5, 3, 'Mr Bazooka');
insert into flights(src_apid, dst_apid, user_id) values(3, 2, 'Mr Bazooka');

select airports.apid
      ,airports.apname
      ,airports.x
      ,airports.y
  from (select max(a.y) as y
          from flights  f
          join airports a on (a.apid = f.src_apid or a.apid = f.dst_apid)
         where f.user_id = 'Family guy'
       ) as northmost 
  join (select a.apid
              ,a.y
          from flights  f
          join airports a on (a.apid = f.src_apid or a.apid = f.dst_apid)
         where f.user_id = 'Family guy'
       ) as userflights on(northmost.y = userflights.y)   
  join airports on(userflights.apid = airports.apid);
```

**Edit. Alternative query that may be less confusing to the optimizer**

```
select airports.*
  from (select case when s.y > d.y then s.apid else d.apid end as apid
              ,case when s.y > d.y then s.y    else d.y    end as northmost
          from flights  f
          join airports s on(f.src_apid = s.apid)
          join airports d on(f.dst_apid = d.apid)
         where f.user_id = 'Family guy'
         order by northmost desc
         limit 1
       ) as user_flights
  join airports on(airports.apid = user_flights.apid);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you added example data while I was writing this. Would you like me use your example instead?

Comment: Ding ding ding, I think we have a winner!  Gets the right results and is super-fast to boot.  The only somewhat scary thing is the temporary table and that DESCRIBE says a filesort is required, but I'll try out a few pathological cases and report back.

Comment: Survey says: a highly respectable 0.23s for >4000 flights and a rather tolerable 3.15s for 40,000 flights.  The bounty is yours!

Comment: Awesome! Which of the queries did you end up using?

Comment: (btw, for some reason a separate click on the bounty award icon next to the answer is needed in order to award the bounty)

Comment: The 2nd version, and bounty awarded now.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
SELECT name,iata,icao,apid,x,y 
FROM airports AS a, flights AS f 
WHERE f.src_apid=a.apid OR f.dst_apid=a.apid
ORDER BY y DESC LIMIT 1
```

You take all flights of the concerned users, order them from northern to southern, and take the first one from the list.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but DESCRIBE says that the query sorts all airports first, then filters, and is thus quite slow: 2.7s for a typical user, even with `y`, `src_apid`, `dst_apid` all indexed.

Comment: The `apid` selection will be arbitrary - you can't guarantee to get the same value, every time.  The fact is, based on comments in lexu's answer -- there's no way to support the requirement of selecting the most Northern airport because the data is not in the system.

Comment: Hmm?   The query above creates a list of the user's airports (3728 and 3992, in the sample data) and sorts these matching airports by `y`, so I don't see how it would ever return the incorrect 7055.

Answer (score 1):

third attempt, using assumed user (userid,name) table

```
select u.name, ap.name
     , ap.iata
     , ap.icao
     , ap.apid
     , ap.x
     , max(ap.y)  
  from users u
     , airports ap
     , flights f
 where u.userid=f.userid
   and (   f.src_apid=ap.apid 
        OR f.dst_apid=ap.apid
       )
group by u.name, ap.name,ap.iata,ap.icao,ap.apid,ap.x
```

you can now restrict the query to the one user you are interested in ..

**comment on GROUP BY:**

- strictly speaking MySQL would allow me to write that group by as 'group by u.name, ap.name'.
- Other SQL dialects don't, they ask that all selected fields that are not aggregated be in the GROUP BY statement.
- So I tend to be 'chicken' when selecting my GROUP BY fields ...

Comment: Should have been a little clearer there: so there are cases like Honolulu which are simultaneously a civilian airport (code PHNL) and a military airfield (code PHIK), and thus show up as two distinct airports that happen to have the same coordinates.  Your query will still return both.

Comment: OK, that will be a bit harder .. which one of the two airports would you want to see? Is there a sorting criterion to be applied? Or is apid (=AirPortID) the same for PHIK and PHNL?

Comment: apid is the unique key for airports, so PHIK and PHNL have different ones, and I'd need to see the one that originally matched -- that is, the apid of the airport that's equal to f.src_apid or f.dst_apid.

A more concrete example: User X has one flight (select from flights where f.uid=X) from Honolulu-PHNL to Sydney, and I want to know User X's northernmost airport.  The answer should be Honolulu-PHNL, not Hickam AFB (PHIK).

Comment: Do you have a table with the users? If you could join against that then you could achieve your goal using a group by.

Comment: Yes, there is a user table, but the query above is unusably slow -- according to describe, it starts off with a temporary table and filesort on 342,118 rows. =(

Comment: @jpatokal: Without geospatial data, there's no way the current query will return the most Northern airport.  Without data to support requirements, you won't reliably get the value you want.

Comment: What exactly is that supposed to mean?  Are you telling me I should intentionally break the airport data and stagger all the values of y just to work around a limitation in SQL?!  To repeat, it's trivial to determine exactly which airfield (apid) the user visited, the problem is getting the apid out of the query.

Comment: @jpatokal: The system is only as good as the data, and if your system doesn't have the data to support your pulled-out-of-the-air requirements... That reality doesn't change if you use NoSQL, SQL, XML, or whatever other technology of choice.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I still have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, but fortunately it doesn't matter, as I just awarded the bounty to an answer that solves the problem quickly and accurately.

Answer (score 1):

OK, perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT name, iata, icao, apid, x, y
  FROM airports
  WHERE y = (SELECT MAX(A.y)
               FROM airports AS a
             INNER JOIN flights AS f
               ON (F.SRC_APID = A.APID OR
                   F.DST_APID = A.APID)
               WHERE f.uid = [user_id]) AND
        apid IN (SELECT SRC_APID AS APID
                   FROM FLIGHTS
                   WHERE UID = [user_id]
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT DEST_APID AS APID
                   FROM FLIGHTS
                   WHERE UID = [user_id])
```

Can't guarantee how this will perform, but perhaps it's a step in the right direction.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 for a good attempt.  Alas, it's only half the speed of Ronnis's answer, since you're effectively getting the user's flights twice.